# Need to write query on two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
Member (member_id,...)
friend-requests(member_id, friend_id)
```

I need to fetch all records from member table with member_id say 19 and which are not in column friend_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from member join friend-requests
on member.member_id=friend_requests.member_id
where
member.member_id=19
and
not exists (select f.member_id from friend-requests f where f.mmeber_id = member.member_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select m.* from Member as m 
where member_id=19 and 
member_id not in (select friend_id from friend_requests where member_id=19)
```